# Factoring $\frac{n(n+1)}2x^2-x-2$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$

Tags: proof-writing, quadratics, factoring, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was factoring quadratic polynomials for high-school practice and I noticed a pattern: $$\begin{align} x^2-x-2 &=(x+1)(x-2) \\ 3x^2-x-2 &=(x-1)(3x-2) \\ 6x^2-x-2 &= (2x+1)(3x-2) \\ 10x^2-x-2 &= (2x-1)(5x+2) \\ 15x^2-x-2 &= (3x+1)(5x-2) \\ 21x^2-x-2 &= (3x-1)(7x+2) \\ &\vdots\end{align}$$ So it seemed that, for any integer $n$, we have:

> $$\frac{n(n+1)}2x^2-x-2=\Big(\left\lceil{\frac n2}\right\rceil x+(-1)^{n+1}\Big)\Big(\left\lceil{n+\frac{(-1)^n}2}\right\rceil x + 2(-1)^n\Big).$$

where the pattern I showed above begins with $n=1$ and ends with $n=6$.

I am not sure how to prove this (assuming it is true). I know that $-2=(-1)^{n+1}\cdot 2(-1)^n$ but I don't know how to prove that: $$\left\lceil{\frac n2}\right\rceil\cdot \left\lceil{n+\frac{(-1)^n}2}\right\rceil=\frac{n(n+1)}2\tag{$\star$}$$ and $$2(-1)^n\left\lceil{\frac n2}\right\rceil+(-1)^{n+1}\left\lceil{n+\frac{(-1)^n}2}\right\rceil=-1$$ which I believe is necessary to prove this conjecture. Since $n$ is an integer, I was thinking of letting $n=\left\lceil\frac k2\right\rceil$ for any real $k$ or something, and I'd assume that $$\left\lceil{\frac n2}\right\rceil=\left\lceil{\frac{\left\lceil{\frac k2}\right\rceil}2}\right\rceil=\left\lceil{\frac k4}\right\rceil$$ but I'm not sure how "round-off arithmetic" works (informally speaking). Any help is appreciated.

---

**Edit:**

Thanks to @lone_student's comment, I have shown $(\star)$ to be true for all $n\in\mathbb Z$ by considering $n$ even and odd.

Lemma:$$\left\lceil {\frac nm}\right\rceil=\left\lfloor{\frac{n-1}m+1}\right\rfloor\tag1$$

Here, $m=2$.

Also: $$n-\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor=\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil\tag2$$
Using these, we can show that:
$$\frac{n(n+1)}2=\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil\cdot\left\lceil{n+\frac{(-1)^n}2}\right\rceil=\underbrace{\Big(n-\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor\Big)}_{\text{By } (2)}\cdot\underbrace{\left\lfloor\frac{2n+(-1)^n-1}2+1\right\rfloor}_{\text{By (1)}}$$

When $n=2k\in\mathbb Z$ we have $$k(2k+1)=\big(2k-\left\lfloor k\right\rfloor\big)\lfloor2k+1\rfloor=k(2k+1)$$ since $k$ and $2k+1$ are integers, and, by definition, $\lceil \alpha\rceil =\lfloor \alpha\rfloor = \alpha$ iff $\alpha\in\mathbb Z$.

Similarly, when $n=2k-1$, we have: $$k(2k-1)=\Big(2k-1-\left\lfloor k-\frac 12\right\rfloor\Big)\lfloor 2k-1\rfloor = k(2k-1)$$ since obviously $\left\lfloor k-\frac 12\right\rfloor = k-1$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$.

---

I believe there was some confusion towards my question: did I mean to factorise the quadratic in terms of $n$ or did I mean to prove specifically the ceiling-function product identity? I did intend to ask a question on the *latter* subject, but I had falsely assumed that the case-by-case polynomial pattern I showed above could *only* be represented through the ceiling functions. This was wrong.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\left[(n+1)x+2\right]\left[nx-2\right]$

Comment: A possible way to prove statements with ceiling functions: take $n=2k$ and $n=2k-1$. This should work, I think.

Comment: Apply the quadratic formula, you can show that the roots are $ \frac{1 \pm (2n+1) }{n(n+1) } = \frac{2}{n}, -\frac{2}{n+1}$, so we do get Rezha's factorization (even if we didn't know how to factorize it initially)

Comment: Not quite sure why you say that.  The ceiling fuction usage here is essentially breaking down into cases, so IMO it's better without it as we don't need to consider cases.

Comment: You should remove that **Edit:** section from the end of your question and post is an answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

To get factors, write $$\frac{n (n+1)}{2}x^2 - x- 2 = \frac{n (n+1)}{2} \left(x^2  -\frac{2}{n(n+1)}x - \frac{2}{n} \cdot \frac{2}{n+1} \right)  = \frac{n (n+1)}{2} \left(x^2  -(\frac{2}{n} -\frac{2}{n+1})x - \frac{2}{n} \cdot \frac{2}{n+1} \right) = \frac{n (n+1)}{2} \left( (x- \frac2n)(x+ \frac{2}{n+1}) \right)$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, I think.

Comment: This does not answer my question *specifically*, however this answer represents the "pattern" without floor and ceiling functions (and, for every integer case $n$, it can be easily manipulated to express each linear factor as having integer $x$-coefficients as desired. This was the part Rezha completed). So this answer nonetheless has my vote.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative factoring method:

When $B^2 - 4AC \geq 0,$ with $A > 0$, then $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ factors into

$A\left(x^2 + \frac{B}{A}x + \frac{C}{A}\right)$

$= A \left[\left(x + \frac{B}{2A}\right)^2 - \frac{B^2}{4A^2} + \frac{C}{A}\right]$.

$= A \left[\left(x + \frac{B}{2A}\right)^2 - \frac{B^2 - 4AC}{4A^2}\right]$

$= A \left[\left(x + \frac{B}{2A}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{\sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}\right)^2\right]$

Under the assumptions, this factors into the difference of two squares as

$$= A\left[\left(x + \frac{B}{2A} + \frac{\sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}\right) \times \left(x + \frac{B}{2A} - \frac{\sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}\right)\right].\tag1$$

With the posted problem, you have that 
$A = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ 
$B = -1$ 
$C = -2$.

From this you can immediately conclude (since $A>0, C<0$) that $B^2 - 4AC > 0$.  Therefore, the formula in (1) above applies.

$\frac{B}{2A} = \frac{-1}{n(n+1)}.$ 
$\frac{\sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A} = \frac{\sqrt{1 + 4n(n+1)}}{n(n+1)} = \frac{(2n+1)}{n(n+1)}.$

Therefore, $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ factors into

$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\left[\left(x + \frac{-1}{n(n+1)} + \frac{(2n+1)}{n(n+1)}\right) \times 
\left(x + \frac{-1}{n(n+1)} - \frac{(2n+1)}{n(n+1)}\right)\right].$

This simplifies into 
$$\frac{1}{2n(n+1)} ~\left\{~
\left[~n(n+1)x + 2n\right] ~\times 
~\left[~n(n+1)x - 2(n+1)~\right]~
\right\}.$$

This further simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{2} \times \left[(n+1)x + 2\right]
 \times \left[nx - 2\right].\tag2$$

In (2) above, either $(n+1)$ or $n$ will be even, thus allowing the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ to be *cleared*.

Therefore, you can forgo any consideration of the floor or ceiling functions, and simply divide the formula mentioned in (2) above into two cases: either $n$ is odd or $n$ is even.

Finally, while I showed the *derivation* of the formula in (2) above, my answer could have been significantly shorter, if I had instead provided a (*sanity-checking*) verification of the formula in (2) above.

That is, if you manually multiply the factors in (2) above, the product will be $Ax^2 + Bx + C$, where $A,B,C$ are as specified in your original question.